# Why Flask session is not working in heroku?

Tags: python, session, heroku, flask

I just created one web app with the help of Flask and Heroku but when I started using session for log in stuff then in local (in my computer) its working fine but when I deployed it on heroku then its showing error: Internal Server Error

Can anyone help me with this ?

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    ''' Home page'''
    if 'username' in session:
        session['logged_in'] = True
    else:
        session['logged_in'] = False
    return render_template('home.html')
```

As soon as it come to 'if' line then server stops and shows error but if i run this locally then it works fine. I just pasted the small part of my code showing where it shows error.

Is it possible that for heroku we need to implement it differently or heroku doesn't support session.

Comment: Add the output of the logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set `app.config['SECRET_KEY']`. If not, flask will report an error.